# Pulling strings from inline java code in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to display the return string of a function using inline java in my jsp page which is done using the following code:

```
<p><%getText("String to print");%></p>
```

This does not appear to return anything even though I have proved through use of

`System.out.println(getText("String to print"));`

that this does actually return a valid non-empty string.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to print the return value of the method, not only execute the method. Use

```
<%= getText("String to print")%>
```

to print it. But, seriously, don't use scriptlets.

Comment: What should I use in place of scriptlets?

Comment: @user3130467 Implement your own `HttpServlet`. Use `JSTL` and `EL`. We have `info` pages for each of those on stackoverflow if you are looking for resources.

Comment: You would need to remove the semi-colon at the end of this scriplet to get it to compile.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid scriptlets, instead use beans:

First, it's best toebale Expression Language:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Use a bean (java class) in your JSP.
First declare the bean:

```
<jsp:useBean id="myclass" class="com.foo.Myclass" scope="session"/>
```

The use it:

```
<p>${myclass.text}</p>
```

The class:

```
public class Myclass {
  public String getText() {
    return "String to print";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like your implementation of getText().  It was very humbling to read.  I am going to look into beans now however I don't quite understand the distinction between the two.  They both seem to do the same thing and take up the same amount of code to write?

Comment: Read : http://www.theserverside.com/feature/Top-5-reasons-that-JSP-scriptlets-suck

Comment: The main distinction is that the display logic (JSP) is separate from the content (Java bean). The `getText` method might not just return a static string, as it does here. It might perform more complex work to arrive at the return value (such as look it up an a database), and this work does not belong in the JSP.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this : `<jsp:expression> getText("String to print") </jsp:expression>`.